# Construtor Javascript para função Canvas DrawImage

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Preciso desenhar diversas imagens em diversos canvas, por isso, gostaria de fazer uma função genérica que me permitisse passar os argumentos para desenhar as imagens posicionadas.

**Pensei na seguinte função genérica:**

```
var drawIt = new function(CanvasCtx,drawObj,x,y) {
   this.CanvasCtx = CanvasCtx;
   this.drawObj = drawObj;
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
      this.drawObj.onload = function(){
         this.CanvasCtx.drawImage(this.drawObj,this.x,this.y)
      }
}
```

**Então quando eu definisse o Canvas e a imagem:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
```

**Eu poderia definir uma função para iniciar on body load:**

```
function drawScreen(){
   drawIt(ctx,Image1,100,100);
}
```

**Porém eu recebo o erro de que a propriedade onload não pode ser atribuida a um objeto não-identificado.**

Alguém pode me ajudar a construir essa função genérica?

Comment: Há alguns problemas no código: qual é o valor atribuido aqui? `this.y = ;` Esse `new` não é necessário: `new function(...)`

Comment: Curiosamente navegadores executam o código da `new function` mas ignoram os argumentos. O nodejs cria um objeto que não pode ser chamado: `typeof drawIt === 'object'`

Comment: Descobri porque o `new function` é válido: https://gist.github.com/qgustavor/9336704

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues `new function(){}` é a mesma coisa que `new referenciaDeFuncaoQualquer()`. A questão é que isso é executado imediatamente. Basicamente, esse código define o construtor e o invoca logo em seguida.

Comment: Isso é mais ou menos o que coloquei na gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está executando um construtor no mesmo momento em que o define (por causa do `new`, como apontado pelo Gustavo Rodrigues). Assim, todos os parâmetros que você está passando são `undefined`.

A gambiarra mais rápida é mover o primeiro bloco de código para dentro de `drawScreen`, mas, se entendi bem o seu código, eu reescreveria tudo de maneira mais simples, sem usar um construtor nem `this`. Isso inclusive resolve um problema que você encontraria logo adiante, pois o valor de `this` dentro do `onload` não seria o que você espera... Minha sugestão é usar isto:

```
var drawIt = function(canvasCtx, drawObj, x, y) {
   drawObj.onload = function(){
       canvasCtx.drawImage(drawObj, x, y);
   }
}
```

O uso é como você previu mesmo:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Image1 = new Image();
Image1.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

function drawScreen(){
   drawIt(ctx,Image1,100,100);
}

drawScreen();
```

<sup>[Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEF8V/)</sup>

Comment: Funcionou! Você tem razão, sua solução é mais simples e direta.